# Fresh Install OSX on new hard drive without the .dmg (iso) file

Tags: macos, hard-drive, install, formatting

Today is the day my hard drive failed.

My issue now is to install OSX (Mavericks) I have purchased to the new HDD.

I have neither a DVD installer nor an iso file nor another Mac Device (but I could ask friends)

How can I proceed to reinstall OS X?

Downloading an iso from the net could solve this? Or should I need my specific iso downloaded from the App Store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To re-install Lion (10.7) or later versions of OS X (including Mavericks), you can use [Internet Recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718). Just boot your MacBook Pro while holding down ⌘R, until the Apple logo appears. You'll see an option for internet recovery (you may need to connect to your Wi-Fi first). Click that and follow the instructions and you'll have a fresh install in a while (it may take some time as it downloads the full installer).